# Widget LTI -> API Authentication

Tags: desire2learn, valence, lti

I am working on an LTI widget, that then needs to authenticate to the API to get additional information.

I'm struggling with trying to figure out how to process the API user authentication, and redirect back retaining the LTI information.

The request string that is returned looks like:

```
Array ( [x_a] => ********************** 
        [x_b] => ********************** 
        [x_c] => *********************************** )
```

The issue is that I have my PHP LTI script setup to only load if it meets the following condition:

```
if(!isset($_REQUEST['lis_outcome_service_url'])
|| !isset($_REQUEST['lis_result_sourcedid'])
|| !isset($_REQUEST['oauth_consumer_key'])
)
```

x_a is the user id, x_b is the user key .. what is x_c?

Any suggestions appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

My answer is referring to the [detailed topic on the IDKey Auth scheme for the Valence dev platform](http://docs.valence.desire2learn.com/basic/auth.html).

The part of the auth sequence you are referring to here is equivalent to the second stage of the sequence, just after the user has successfully authenticated themselves (when you chain on the back of an LTI launch like this, you know that the user driving the user-agent has already authenticated, because they wouldn't have otherwise been able to do the LTI launch) and the service sends back the long-lived user tokens to your service.

See steps *5 to 7* in the *sequence notes*, in the section called [Using a third-party web application](http://docs.valence.desire2learn.com/basic/auth.html#using-a-third-party-web-application) in the IDKey Authentication docs topic:

> **x_a={*tokenID*}** – Unique ID associated with the long-lived token: the web application can provide this ID so that the service can precisely locate the web application/user context.
>
> **x_b={*tokenKey*}** – Key associated with the long-lived token: the web application can use this as a key to generating session signatures.
>
> **x_c={*tokenSig*}** – Token identity signature: the service joins (and delimits with an ampersand) the User ID (tokenID) and the User Key (tokenKey) to use as the base-string, and uses the Application Key as the key.

Note that you will need to use your Valence Application ID/Key pair in order to verify the token signature contained in `x_c`.

**Remote plugins**. Note that the [Brightspace Remote Plugin service](http://docs.valence.desire2learn.com/ui-ext/rplugins.html) is a convenience service wrapper around LTI/external learning tools. The docs about Remote Plugins contain a fairly detailed walkthrough/sample that showcases a simple Python web-service Tool Provider implementation that receives a Brightspace LTI launch, and can turn around and use Valence API calls to get more information. You might find it useful to have a close look at that.

Comment: Ok, so then after verifying `x_c`, what is the proper url to redirect back to?

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand what you're asking here. I've amended the answer to include more info about auth workflow and LTI that might be useful to you.